# Mass conversion of Word 2003 to Word 2007 without using Word automation?

Tags: .net, automation, ms-word

Is there a way to efficiently convert Word 2003 documents to Word 2007 without using ole automation? I'd like to use DotNet if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several 3rd party libs out there (e.g. Aspose.Words or Syncfusion) that do this kind of conversion reading & writing Word 2003 and 2007 etc natively...

I can only speak for Aspose which I have good experience with in several projects.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting a copy of Aspose.Words. It works good enough for my purposes.